# Google Custom Search's refinement doesn't redirect to different website.

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search and trying to use Refinement to redirect search queries to other websites.

I follow the example from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/refinements#redirect but it doesn't work.

When I click a refinement link (tab), instead of redirecting, it just shows "No Results" on the same page.

---

Here is my XML CSE Context code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CustomSearchEngine id="<my_search_engine_id>" creator="<my_creator_id>" language="en" encoding="UTF-8" enable_suggest="true">
  <Title>my.domain.name</Title>
  <Context>
    <Facet>
      <FacetItem title="Google Scholars">
        <Label name="google_scholars" mode="FILTER"/>
        <Redirect url="http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=$q"/>
      </FacetItem>
    </Facet>
    <BackgroundLabels>
      <Label name="_cse_4zii28iwa6o" mode="FILTER" />
      <Label name="_cse_exclude_4zii28iwa6o" mode="ELIMINATE" />
    </BackgroundLabels>
  </Context>
  <LookAndFeel nonprofit="false" element_layout="8" theme="7" custom_theme="true" text_font="Arial, sans-serif" url_length="full" element_branding="show" enable_cse_thumbnail="true" promotion_url_length="full" ads_layout="1">
    <Logo />
    <Colors url="#008000" background="#FFFFFF" border="#FFFFFF" title="#0000CC" text="#000000" visited="#0000CC" title_hover="#0000CC" title_active="#0000CC" />
    <Promotions title_color="#0000CC" title_visited_color="#0000CC" url_color="#008000" background_color="#FFFFFF" border_color="#336699" snippet_color="#000000" title_hover_color="#0000CC" title_active_color="#0000CC" />
    <SearchControls input_border_color="#D9D9D9" button_border_color="#666666" button_background_color="#CECECE" tab_border_color="#E9E9E9" tab_background_color="#E9E9E9" tab_selected_border_color="#FF9900" tab_selected_background_color="#FFFFFF" />
    <Results border_color="#FFFFFF" border_hover_color="#FFFFFF" background_color="#FFFFFF" background_hover_color="#FFFFFF" ads_background_color="#FDF6E5" ads_border_color="#FDF6E5" />
  </LookAndFeel>
  <AdSense />
  <EnterpriseAccount />
  <ImageSearchSettings enable="true" />
  <autocomplete_settings />
  <sort_by_keys label="Relevance" key="" />
  <sort_by_keys label="Date" key="date" />
  <cse_advance_settings enable_speech="true" enable_facet_search="true" />
</CustomSearchEngine>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer from the Google Enterprise Support team (4th August 2014) as follows:

> "No, currently this feature is not  supported and there are no plans
>   to implement this feature in near future as well. We will be updating
>   the documentation that this feature is not supported in custom search
>   element code.
>
> You can consider using XML API to retrieve results in XML , customize
>   and display to end users as per your requirement."

Comment: Hi Supasate, did you ever end up figuring out a workaround for this?

Comment: No, I didn't. At that time, I removed it out from my feature list because it was not a critical requirement.